# I am getting the error AsyncTask doesn't override methods from superclass?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, overriding

It says that Async isnt overriding any methods from superclass.
This is an example taken from tutorialspoint website.
This just doesnt seem to work. Please do help.
Thanks in advance.
*Edit: I have uploaded the complete java file.

```
public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask{

        private Context context;
        private TextView statusField,userField;

        public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,TextView userField) {
            this.context = context;
            this.statusField = statusField;
            this.userField = userField;
    }

        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try{
                String username = (String)arg0[0];
                String password = (String)arg0[1];

                String link="http://127.0.0.1/login.php";
                String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.write( data );
                wr.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                return (sb.toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
               return (new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
            this.userField.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: which class you are extending

Comment: My guess is that you're not using the right type arguments for `AsyncTask` - but we can't see that, because you've only provided the method, not a [mcve].

Comment: I am extending AsyncTask@Mr.Popular

Comment: post your full async task class code..

Comment: @NitinMamidala. We also need the types. You must have something like `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`. What does that part look like in your code?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 i have uploaded the full code

Comment: try:    public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I have uploaded the whole java file, please check now.

Comment: Right, so you're just subclassing the raw type `AsyncTask`. As others have said, you should probably subclass `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`. Given that you've already been told how to fix it, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

Use the above code it will do the work

Comment: if you need preExecute and postExcute you have to extend the above code or if you need need to override only doinBackground you can use                       public class Sample extends
             AsyncTask{

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
          
            return null;

        }
    }